# PL/SQL Not Exists Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help to solve this issue. The Driver_ID exists in two tables, Driver and Driver_Deliveries. I need it to display the First_Name, Surname & Driver_ID for the Driver ID's that do not appear in the Driver_Deliveries table. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer with Oracle 11G.

```
DECLARE
  FIRSTNAME   VARCHAR2(20);
  SUR_NAME      VARCHAR2(20);
  DRIVERID VARCHAR2(5);

BEGIN

FOR i IN
(
    SELECT
        FIRST_NAME,
        SURNAME,
        a.DRIVER_ID
        INTO
        FIRSTNAME, SUR_NAME, DRIVERID
    FROM


        DRIVER_DELIVERIES,
        DRIVER a,


        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DRIVER_DELIVERIES WHERE DRIVER_DELIVERIES.DRIVER_ID = a.DRIVER_ID);


       )
LOOP


        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FIRST NAME :' ||I.FIRST_NAME);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SURNAME :' || I.SURNAME);

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELIVERY JOB REQUIRED: YES ');



  END LOOP;
END;
```

Here's the error stack:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 23, column 9:
PL/SQL: ORA-00903: invalid table name
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 23, column 106:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   loop
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: So, what's wrong with your solution (if anything)?

Comment: Also, does this need to be in PL/SQL? It can be done more directly in plain SQL.

Comment: @mustaccio this is what I get:  06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @mathguy yes I need to do it in PL/SQL

Comment: You have a bunch of syntax errors in your code: the unnecessary `INTO` clause, lack of a join between the two tables, an extra comma before the where clause, possibly others. May be you can start by taking an example from Oracle documentation and build upon that.

Comment: @VegetaZA - that's part of the error; can you add the whole error stack to the question as you're missing the important bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select *into* something with a simple query in a PL/SQL block, but you've taken that rule too far; because your cursor loop variable `i` is an implicit record type that is already available to take the query results.

You also have an extra comma in your cursor query's select list, and the from clause. And an extra semicolon after the `where` clause.

So with that loop syntax you need:

```
...
FOR i IN
(
    SELECT
        FIRST_NAME,
        SURNAME,
        a.DRIVER_ID
    FROM
        DRIVER_DELIVERIES,
        DRIVER a
    WHERE
...
```

Though you should really use explicit join syntax, which would make it more obvious that you currently have no link between the two tables in your `where` clause. But you don't actually want to refer to `driver_deliveries` there at all - you're getting all the data from the `driver` table. You *only* need to refer to that within the `exists` clause. (And I've just noticed you've spelled the table name incorrectly in that clause too).

So modifying that further:

need:

```
...
FOR i IN
(
    SELECT
        FIRST_NAME,
        SURNAME,
        DRIVER_ID
    FROM
        DRIVER a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT null FROM DRIVER_DELIVERIES
        WHERE DRIVER_DELIVERIES.DRIVER_ID = a.DRIVER_ID)
)
LOOP
...
```

You don't appear to need PL/SQL for this, but if you have to...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked, I really appreciate it! I've only started learning this recently so that's why I've made these mistakes.

Comment: You need to get the hang of interpreting the error stack, and looking at (and around) the lines they point to. It's not always clear but these errors were flagged quite clearly.